# Power BI - Count items over time period until status change

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have tried looking online for a similar case but struggling to come up with a solution.

I have two main tables:

A table that has an identifier and a date that the identifier was either created or updated on.

| File name | Identifier | Update Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File 1 | Apple | 12/02/2021 |
| File 2 | Orange | 25/04/2021 |
| File 3 | Apple | 27/06/2021 |

A second table that has a rating that is linked (via the file name field) to each of the above identifiers on their specific dates.

| File name | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| File 1 | C |
| File 2 | B |
| File 3 | A |

What I need is a measure that tells me how many of the identifiers had a rating of B or C during each month.

For example, for every month between 02/2021 and 06/2021, there were 2 identifiers that had a rating of either B or C. This changed to 1 from 06/2021 onwards.

I have a date lookup table and have created start and end of month columns in the first table that have a relationship to the date lookup table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your question above and expand on "I have a date lookup table and have created start and end of month columns in the first table that have a relationship to the date lookup table." Provide a screen grab of the data model showing the table names, columns and relationships between these three tables.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that measure is not the best thing to use for this.

If there is one to one cardinality between the tables, you are not using the filtration in visuals and you have to use a measures.

```
MeasureA1 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Rating), AND(RELATED(Rating) = "A", UpdateDate.[Month] = 1)) // For each rating and month
```

Much better way is to use filtration in visuals. Create just one measure.

```
Measure = COUNT(Rating)
```

And create table or cards filtrated with rating.

You can also create summarized table.